# Could a Soyuz-MS deorbit after a failure of its deorbit engine?

Tags: propulsion, soyuz-spacecraft, deorbit

The scenario: A Soyuz-MS spacecraft is on-orbit and ready for its deorbit burn.  The crew then discover that there is a fault in the propulsion system and the deorbit engine can't fire.  The craft is stable, in the correct orbit, and (apart from a non-functional engine) is fully intact.  Is there any way the crew can return safely to Earth?

Nature of the failure (choose one):

- Either the N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub> or UDMH feedlines (you pick which) are fully blocked.  Could the deorbit engine be used as a cold gas thruster?  If so, would it have sufficient thrust?
- Total failure of the N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub>/UDMH subsystem; it's intact but completely non-functional.  Do the other thrusters (such as the H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> thrusters on descent module) have sufficient thrust to deorbit the craft?  Are there any outside-of-the-box solutions?

Docking with a rescue vehicle/tug is specifically excluded.

Comment: On most craft the RCS can be used as a backup deorbit method.

Comment: @OrganicMarble would that include the H2O2 thrusters on their own?  I believe the primary RCS thrusters on MS are N2O4/UDMH based.

Comment: No, the orbital RCS.

Comment: The answer depends on the redundancy setup of the ship's prop system and exactly what you are failing. Not in a position to look into the former now.

Comment: Right.  It looks like there are RCS thrusters on the orbital module as well but it's not clear where they're tanked from.

Comment: If this question doesn't get any responses in the next couple of days I'll split it up into multiple questions, one for each specific scenario.